# cannot coerce type 'environment' to vector of type 'character'

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to make a shiny interactive UI to read a file, but I am getting following error:

> cannot coerce type 'environment' to vector of type 'character'

Part of the code being used for the same is:

```
library(shiny)

ui= fluidPage(
  titlePanel("TF-IDF")
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file", "Upload the File ")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("contents")
    )
     )

)

shinyServer= function(input,output){
  datain1= reactive({
    file1= input$file
    if(is.null(file1)){return()}
    read.table(file=file1$datapath, sep= input$sep, header= input$header , stringsAsFactors = input$stringAsFactors)
  }

  )
}

shinyApp(ui= shinyUI, server = shinyServer)
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a typo in your `shinyApp` call. Try with this one:

```
shinyApp(ui= ui, server = shinyServer)
```